Replace <%= BASE_URL %> inside node_modules dependencies
I'm migrating from Vue CLI to Vite. Vue CLI (I guess through Webpack) apparently replaced <%= BASE_URL %> with the correct value, and Vite does not.
Unfortunately these are in a couple of node_modules dependencies so I can't easily remove these occurences, and so I'm getting some errors like this 404 GET /%3C%=%20BASE_URL%20%%3Ecss/vue-skeletor.css
I tried:

Using Vite 5.2.0, which is supposed to handle replacements natively, although I understand it replaces %VAR% and not <%= VAR %>
Using aliases
Using a plugin as suggested in String replacements in index.html in vite, to manually do the replacement with a regexp in the transform hook

The thing is I don't think the build system even processes node_modules, because when I add a load hook and print all paths it looks at it doesn't look at node_modules/.
I can solve the issue at the dev-server level, but it seems nasty and doesn't translate in production.
